# Filter function for req.query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

at the moment i have this:

```
router.get('/contatos',function(req,res){
if(req.query.nome){
     Contato.find({ nome: req.query.nome }, function (err, contato) {
         console.log(contato);
        if (JSON.stringify(contato) == "[]") {
            return res.status(404).json({ Error: "that contact doesn't exist" });
        }

        if (err) {
            return res.status(500);
        }
        return res.send(contato);
    });   
}

if(req.query.email){
     Contato.find({ email: req.query.email }, function (err, contato) {
        if (!contato) {
            return res.status(404).json({ Error: "that contact doesn't exist" });
        }

        if (err) {
            return res.status(500);
        }
        return res.send(contato);
    });   
}

if(Object.keys(req.query).length === 0){
 Contato.find(function (err, contatos) {
        if (JSON.stringify(contatos) == "{}") {
            return res.status(404).json({ Error: "there are no contacts" });
        }

        if (err) {
            return res.status(500);
        }
        return res.send(contatos);
    }).populate('emergencia');      
}

if(!req.query.nome && !req.query.email){
    return res.status(400);
}

});
```

as you guys can see, the mongo query is almost the same the only thing that changes are the values that i pass, so to change this i tried to do a function **like this:**

```
function filtro(campo,valor,req,res){
if(arguments[0] != "undefined" && arguments[1] != "undefined"){
   // i pass no parameters to filtro so here i just get all values  
}
else{
    Contato.find({campo:valor},function(err,contatos){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500);
        }
        return res.send(contatos);
    });
}

}
```

then above in the first code i placed i just replace the mongo data with the `return filtro("email",req.query.email)`
**AND**
`return filtro("nome",req.query.nome)`

i want to know if what i am doing is correct, i just miss something because on postman it doesn't give me any response it keeps loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify it a little, you could do something like....

```
router.get('contatos', function(req, res){
    var query = {};
    if(req.query.nome) query.nome = req.query.nome;
    if(req.query.email) query.email = req.query.email;

    Contato.find(query, function (err, contato) {
        if(err) return res.json({status : 500, error : err});
        if(!contato) return res.json({status : 404, error : "Contact not found"});

        return res.json(contato);
    });   

}
```

Comment: awesome, great solution didn't remember that :D, can i ask you something else really fast?

Comment: i got the logic, that is more important to me then the code

Comment: basicly i want to do parcialUpdates in my contacts so i must do something like this /contatos/:id/name, but that name can be 3 different things: name,email or phone, how can i check that and how i construct the route?